# Intellisense stops working in aspx files when identity impersonate is set

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, s#arp-architecture

This one has me stumped.

I have an MVC 2.0 environment in a S#arp layout, everything works great, and I have Intellisense working in my aspx file (for things like HTML helpers and Model properties)

As soon as I add the line:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="xyz" password="abc" />
```

To my web.config, I lose Intellisense on my aspx files!

Does anyone have any idea of why this is happening?  Or have any experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally figured this out.

It looks like the impersonated user needs write access to a folder within the S#arp folder structure.  I still don't know which since I assumed \bin and that didn't work.

So, give the impersonated user read/write access to your project folder and intellisense is back!